# GRUB still showing windows 7 boot instead of windows 10

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows-7, windows-10

So, I have dual boot on my notebook which are Ubuntu and Windows 7.
But recently, I upgraded my windows 7 to windows 10. But when I startup my notebook, it still shows Windows 7 instead of Windows 10. Although, if I choose Windows 7 boot from it, it will boot windows 10.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried editing the grub file?

Comment: @gingamann Oh I can do that? sorry I am still so newb in Ubuntu.. Ill try that too..

Comment: Hey choz, that's really smooth. I'm holding off the update as it might overwrite the MBR with Windows boot loader. Except for the old grub label entry (Windows 7) displayed issue, did you face any other issue?

Comment: @zuke nope so far, its just during installation u have to wait for it to keep restarting and in my case, i have to wait to choose the windows loader on boot up which is pretty sucky.. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [GRUB2 shows Windows 7 instead of Windows 10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/666317/grub2-shows-windows-7-instead-of-windows-10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can  try manually editing the Grub file to rename the Microsoft instance from 7 to 10.

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Tq.. it works..

Comment: cool stuff bud :)

Comment: The file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is normally auto-generated by `update-grub` / `grub-mkconfig`, so any changes you make to the file directly will be lost when you install software updates that need a grub update.

Answer (score 5):

you have dual boot system in which you are using ubuntu grub . you have upgraded window but ubuntu system grub don't know about your change . it is simply searching in particular disk that you assign and loading window . so you have to change manually in grub.cfg file . open terminal in ubuntu and run command  `sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg` . here you need to search entry like:

```
menuentry “Windows 7 (on /dev/sda1)” {
insmod ntfs
set root=’(hd0,1)’
```

change Window 7 to window 10 or whatever name you want to give and save file and restart system next time you will see change .

Answer (score 1):

It is just a name and you can easily change that!

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install grub-customizer