# Grub2 to see new Windows 10 loader instead of Windows 8 loader

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows-10

I was running a dual-boot of Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8 Pro. I recently took advantage of the free Windows upgrade and upgraded my Windows 8 to 10, however; whenever I start up my machine, Grub2 still lists my Windows loader as Windows 8 and whenever I select Windows I get the old Windows 8 logging on screen for a while before getting into Windows 10.
Am new to Ubuntu so I don't know if this is a Grub2 problem or something else.
Please help

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I did run sudo update-grub alas with no change when I booted up again.

Comment: Dude I had the same problem as you and this solved it: http://askubuntu.com/q/654905/436551

Comment: Editing the grub configurations worked, thanks man!