# GRUB2 shows wrong Windows version

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

This is a Q&A that I recently have figured out, so I have posted the answer below.

After installing Windows 10, every time I get a kernel update or I run the `update-grub2` it always shows `Windows 7` or `Windows Recovery Environment` instead of `Windows 10`.  How do I fix this permanently?

Comment: Those changes already exist in (my Mint 19.2) /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft, but it still returns "Windows Vista". Note that, when the dual-boot system was Windows 7, it returned the correct value, so it appears it is the source of the information that is missing.

Comment: @cdg This should be asked at [Linux&Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) as this site is for [official Ubuntu flavors](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) only.  Also, you should file a bug report with [Mint Development](http://developer.linuxmint.com/reporting-an-issue.html) if you already have all this as they may not be detecting it correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update 2022-10-23:**  It appears the grub team has not updated for Windows 11 yet as it might show Windows Vista, so I have added how to make the changes in the answer below.

---

The reason why it still shows `Windows 7` or `Windows Recovery Environment` instead of `Windows 10` is that the file `/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft` does not contain the label for `Windows 10`, so during the `os-prober` detection of the OS it falls back to `Windows 7` or `Windows Recovery Environment`.

To correct this, you need to make the following changes to the following file (I am going to put gedit as the editor, but use what you want):

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft
```

**NOTE:  You should always make a backup of a file before modifying it!**

*Added for Windows 11 now as well as it might be detected as Windows Vista.*

```
if item_in_dir -q bootmgr "$2"; then
        # there might be different boot directories in different case as:
        # boot Boot BOOT
        for boot in $(item_in_dir boot "$2"); do
                bcd=$(item_in_dir bcd "$2/$boot")
                if [ -n "$bcd" ]; then
                        if grep -qs "W.i.n.d.o.w.s. .1.1" "$2/$boot/$bcd"; then
                                long="Windows 11"
                        elif grep -qs "W.i.n.d.o.w.s. .1.0" "$2/$boot/$bcd"; then
                                long="Windows 10"
                        elif grep -qs "W.i.n.d.o.w.s. .8" "$2/$boot/$bcd"; then
                                long="Windows 8 (loader)"
                        elif grep -qs "W.i.n.d.o.w.s. .7" "$2/$boot/$bcd"; then
                                long="Windows 7 (loader)"
```

the above section is around line 34 of the file.  All you should have to do is change the `if` statement at the beginning of the line to `elif` and then add the section for Windows 11 starting with the `if` line above the one for Windows 10.

Once saved, then running `os-prober` now looks like this:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo os-prober
/dev/sdc1:Windows 11:Windows:chain
```

then running `update-grub2` it will now make the updates to your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` permanent anytime you get a kernel update so it will show the correct version of Windows now (example below):

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/lubuntu-grub-theme.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-50-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-52-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows 11 on /dev/sdc1
done
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Has this been posted upstream (as bug/fix), for Grub2 maintainers?

Comment: @david6 I have no idea if it has been.  I just made the discovery last night while trying to learn more about GRUB2 and how it determines what OS it finds.

Comment: The '20microsoft' scripts looks messy, and may need other improvements.