# GRUB not detecting windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu, but it seems like it can't detect my windows partition. On the "try ubuntu" option,  I want to see if it detects my windows partition.

After running

> sudo os-prober

I get get only

> /dev/sda1:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows:chain

Is there a problem with that, or should I still proceed in installing Ubuntu using the "Something else" option and creating my own partitions

Comment: If you have installed Ubuntu already, then it sounds to me that the GRUB is missing information as to what it detects.  Please check this answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/666317/grub2-shows-windows-7-or-windows-recovery-environment-instead-of-windows-10/666318#666318) to fix the GRUB files so that Windows is detected properly.

Comment: @Terrance I have not installed Ubuntu already. I clicked "try ubuntu" in the boot screen.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you trying to install?  14.04?  15.10?

Comment: @Terrance 14.04

Comment: Is it Windows 10 on your system?

Comment: Yes windows 10 is on my system

Comment: OK, I am going to check the GRUB files on a 14.04 LiveCD.  Give me a few here

Comment: Just as I thought.  The file `/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft` that is on the LiveCD / USB does not contain the correct information, hence that is why it does not detect your OS.

Comment: I guess from a terminal you could edit the file with nano:  `nano /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft`

Comment: And change it the same way I did in what I wrote.  It will not be permanent, but it might help you install Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I just created a LiveUSB with a 1GB Persistent file on it, and I was able to modify `/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft` file and it kept my settings persistent after a reboot.  It was able to see the Windows 10 installation on a system.

Comment: @Terrance gedit /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft

Comment: @It'sWillem That works too.  I prefer vi though, but I don't normally suggest that one to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by installing Ubuntu 15.10 on LiveUSB instead.

Comment: Or this works because it has the updated grub files contained in the LiveUSB.  =)