# Option "Install alongside Windows 10" doesn't appear when installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot

When I try to install Ubuntu 14.04 from a usb drive the option, 'Install alongside Windows 10' doesn't appear. Should I install it anyway, or if not, what can I do so that option appears?

Comment: Did you set up the USB to have a persistent file so it keeps changes?

Comment: @Terrance not sure. I just mounted the image using  the Pen Drive Universal USB Installer

Comment: I think during the creation of the USB it defaults to persistent file.   I would have to check.  Anyway, the reason why it is not seeing Windows 10, is there is a file that it uses to detect mounted OSes and is missing the label to see Windows 10.  Take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/666317/grub2-shows-windows-7-or-windows-recovery-environment-instead-of-windows-10).  It is best to modify the USB after you boot to it.

Comment: I recommend you to format your USB and prepare it once again using Unetbootin.
Also check if your .iso file is complete.
Here is an official Ubuntu guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: Have you turned off Windows fast start up or always on hibernation. Have you used Windows to shrink the NTFS partition to make unallocated space & rebooted immediately so it can run chkdsk? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI And this, but 10 should be almost same as 8: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The option of "Install alongside windows10" didn't appear while installing Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem was the Ubuntu ISO image on my USB drive was NOT UEFI bootable.  I reformatted my USB that will be able to boot a UEFI system.

I used Rufus to create a [UEFI bootable USB stick](https://www.vanstechelman.eu/content/creating-an-uefi-bootable-linux-usb-stick) 
(Note: If you are using fixed disks/hard drives, try <kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>F</kbd> in Rufus to enable it's detection)

After I did this, it worked perfectly!! I was able to install Ubuntu along-side windows!

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with a workaround here.

If you cannot do it (install alongside Windows) with your installation wizard anyway, you may choose to boot with your installation media into the Live system, adjust the partition of Windows using `gparted` (it is a GUI tool), and manually create Ubuntu partitions during installation.

If you made your installation media using the official image, when you boot with it, you should either (1) see a grub menu asking you to boot into Live system or to install Ubuntu, or (2) boot into installation wizard directly, but can exit the wizard and enter Live system. The Live system looks like a normal Ubuntu desktop, and you can run `gparted` any way you like.

Be careful when you modify partitions, though. There's risk that you make your Windows no longer bootable, or lose your data on the Windows partition. Better not move the starting position of your Windows partition(s).