# Dual boot goes to grub command line and Windows won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, boot-repair

I have dual boot, ubuntu 20.04 and windows 11. I think I did updates on windows and ubuntu. Now when I turn on the computer it goes to grub command line (it didn't before). I can exit that and get to the normal selection screen (where there are 10 seconds to choose what to boot), and I can boot ubuntu from there. But when I try to boot windows, the screen just goes blank and nothing happens. I have tried the ubuntu boot repair with a usb stick, results didn't change.

Edit: If I select a windows boot loader from bios, it will load.

Comment: You might need to update GRUB from Ubuntu as the entry for loading might have changed.  `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Ok I thought the boot repair disk had a message saying that it did that. I'll try that

Comment: If you have the link it gives you from the  Boot Repair, that could really help us help you too!

Comment: updating grub did not change results

Comment: Ah, sounds like you have UEFI loading where you don't need GRUB.  You need to access your BIOS / UEFI by pressing DEL on the keyboard during boot.  Some motherboard manufacturers use different key combinations to access the BIOS.  You may have to look your up.

Comment: I can access bios, what do I turn off?

Comment: I am not sitting in front of UEFI right now, but you would just have to select Windows from your boot order or boot screen in the BIOS / UEFI screen.

Comment: I can select windows boot from the selection screen when it gets to that. But the screen just goes blank after. I have to exit from grub to get to this screen. I'm not sure why grub shows up on boot up though, nor why windows doesn't load when selected. If I select windows from the bios screen, not sure what difference that will make, but I can try. But it's not a convenient way to start windows, normally I have 10 seconds to select it with the ubuntu seletions.

Comment: So I can start windows if I select it from bios screen, thanks,, but not from the ubuntu selection screen that gives 10 seconds.

Comment: I guess there is a possibility that Windows 11 isn't detecting properly for GRUB, so you might want to see this  https://askubuntu.com/questions/666317/grub2-shows-wrong-windows-version  Other than that, I am out of ideas.

Comment: I tried that. It still goes blank when starting windows from the 10 second screen.

Comment: Still goes to grub command line on startup, that I have to exit from, then it goes to ubuntu selection screen