# Windows 11 not found by update-grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, windows

I have a system with both windows 11 and kubuntu 22.10 installed; in which I am able to successfully boot into each of these via changing boot order in bios. Kubuntu appears inside of the grub bootloader on startup but windows 11 doesn't.

I have tried running `os-prober`, but afterwards `update-grub` still fails to find windows.

Also I have tried adding `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to /etc/default/grub.

The following is the output for the `os-prober` command:

```
jmpris@kubuntu:~$ sudo os-prober
/dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
```

Here is my output from `update-grub`:

```
jmpris@kubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub2
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-21-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
jmpris@kubuntu:~$
```

Comment: You can try https://askubuntu.com/questions/666317/grub2-shows-wrong-windows-version/666318#666318 but I don't know since yours is finding the EFI.

Comment: Is bitlocker on? Or is Windows fast startup still on. Note that Windows updates may turn fast startup back on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @oldfred I have checked and both fast startup and hibernation are disabled. As for bitlocker the `Get-BitlockerVolume` command says that all of my drives are FullyDecrypted and `manage-bde -status` states None for BitLocker Version on all drives.

Comment: The report will show boot configuration. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair I prefer to turn off os-prober and add my own boot stanza to 40_custom. But usually easier to copy it from first run where os-prober found Windows.

Comment: @oldfred Here is the link to the boot-repair summary: https://pastebin.com/REyvkPJv

Comment: Not sure why it sees Windows as Windows 7, must not be updated to see Windows 11. Do not see any issue. You can add Windows boot stanza: https://askubuntu.com/questions/659528/grub-menu-with-windows-10-and-ubuntu-14-04/659910#659910 Example UEFI stanza: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425637/how-can-i-add-windows-11-to-grub-menu Separately best not to mount using device like /dev/sda1 as which drive is sda, is controlled by UEFI on drive discovery. While SSD may normally be first, it may not always be. Use UUID or label.